# How many ticktocks?

Tags: mathematics

There's a broken clock. the interval between its two ticks is longer than usual so that it loses 6 minutes an hour.

How many ticks should a blind person hear so that he/she be informed of real 6 minutes past?

P.S. I have seen this puzzle in a non-English puzzle quiz and translated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 324

Because:

> 60 minutes pass when the clock counts only 54 minutes.
>  So 6 minutes pass when the clock counts 5.4 minutes.
>  5.4 minutes = $60 \times 5.4$ ticks = 324

Answer (score 1):

a blind person should count:

> 328 ticks

A "normal" clock ticks 1 time per second so 3600 times per hour. Now our clock ticks the same amount of times in 66 minutes or 3960seconds. the interval between 2 ticks is 3960/3600 = 1.1s .

To get 6 minutes a blind person would need to count 360/1.1

> = 327.2727... times

Comment: Marius did it well. take a look at it.